# How to find the likelihood that a multivariate observation could have been generated by a given copula?

Tags: copula

I can take a set of multivariate observations belonging to a class, and use them to generate a copula. This can then be used to generate synthetic multivariate data which are statistically compatible with the data originally observed.

If I now have a new observation which I wish to classify, how may I calculate the likelihood that the observation could have been generated by that copula?

Comment: I think you are looking for a cluster or classification copula model. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dr.Alenezi - Yes, ultimately, but I'm interested in what's going on under the hood as well.